# Re-create database at runtime using EclipseLink

Tags: java, database, entity, eclipselink

Is there a way to recreate the database dynamically at Run-Time in EclipseLink?

Right now I have it that if the database does not exist, it creates the database at compilation time :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="DefaultUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                value="database" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="INFO" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="create" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

However, I want to be able to Drop, and Recreate the database while the application is running. I.E when a user passes in some special flag, I want to call something that will drop the current database, and regenerate it.

I found that you can do that in Hibernate using the [SchemaExport class](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>` into persistence.xml.

It will delete all table and create it again. Be careful, all your earlier data will be lost.

Comment: Which is why I don't want to do that. I Only want to drop the tables and recreate based on some flag (Which can be passed in as an a config setting)

Answer (score 0):

absolutely.  Properties can be added dynamically at runtime, so you can add the "eclipselink.ddl-generation" with value "drop-and-create-tables" when you create the EntityManagerFactory for the first time to have it drop and create the database.  Of course, this isn't much use to a running app where you want to change things on the fly.

To get around this, EclipseLInk has a few tricks that allow dynamic changes and reloading of the persistence unit.  Try

```
Map properties = new HashMap();
properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "drop-and-create-tables");
properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode", "database");
//this causes DDL generation to occur on refreshMetadata rather than wait until an em is obtained
properties.put("eclipselink.deploy-on-startup", "true");
JpaHelper.getEntityManagerFactory(em).refreshMetadata(properties);
```

The org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.JPAHelper class is just used to unwrap the Factory to get a JpaEntityManagerFactory instance to make the non-JPA refreshMetadata call.  Any number of properties or settings can be changed, and any new EntityManagers obtained after the refresh call will reflect those changes.